# Android: don't boot Launcher - run my application instead on startup

Tags: android

I've built Android from source and would like to launch directly into my application and NOT launch Launcher at all. Does anyone know what to change to launch an applicable .apk instead of Launcher on boot?

Running launcher causes a host of problems with my masking the fact Android is running.
 - The unlock screen
 - The status bar
 - The menu & home icons

It would be best simply not to launch Launcher and go directly into the application from the Android boot logo.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I did but have since gone onto another project...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is much easier solution that allows you not to rebuild Android. Just fill the main `Activity` of your application (in `AndroidManifest.xml`) with:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

And after first start, reboot your device and than make your application's main `Activity` the default Home Screen (check the `CheckBox` at the bottom of choose dialog).

Comment: This is not working for me on android 6.0.1 or 8.1